# How to add context in a feature rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I want to add context into my feature rspec, but I am not sure what makes sense between context and scenario.

Here is what I have so far:

```
feature 'As an admin I manage the orders of the system' do
  context 'Logged in user who is an admin' do
    before(:each) do
      admin = create(:admin_user)
      login_as(admin, :scope => :user)
    end

    scenario 'User sees all the orders' do
      visit admin_orders_path
      expect(page).to have_content('List of orders')
    end
  end

  context 'Logged in user who is not an admin' do
    before(:each) do
      user = create(:user)
      login_as(user, :scope => :user)
    end

    scenario 'User cannot see the orders' do
      visit admin_orders_path
      expect(current_path).to eq('/')
    end
  end

end
```

Does this makes sense, or I should decide between using scenario or context, but not both together?

Comment: This is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

The way I am thinking my tests is the following:

`Feature` specs are high-level tests for testing the whole "picture" - functionality of your application.

So, core functionality of my app: `features` with `scenarios` inside.

Unit tests: `describe` and `it`.

You can use `context` in both though.

From the [documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/feature-specs/feature-spec):
The `feature` and `scenario` correspond to `describe` and `it`, respectively. These methods are simply aliases that allow feature specs to
read more as customer tests and acceptance tests.

So, in your case I would do the following:

```
feature 'As an admin I manage the orders of the system' do
  context 'user is logged in as' do 

    before(:each) do
      user = create(:user)
      login_as(user, :scope => :user)
    end

    scenario 'an admin, can see all the orders' do
       visit admin_orders_path
       expect(page).to have_content('List of orders')
     end

    scenario 'not an admin, cannot see the orders' do
      visit admin_orders_path
      expect(current_path).to eq('/')
  end
end
```

One `context`, two `scenarios` for the user. Also, I would think a little bit more about the description of the feature. Hope that helps and doens't confuse you more!

Also, I like to see my tests like the "heartbeat" of my app. First, you go from feature testing (outside, core functionality) and then you go inside(unit test). And that thing is repeating all the time, like a "heartbeat"

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/feature-specs/feature-spec):

> The feature and scenario DSL correspond to `describe` and `it`,
>   respectively. These methods are simply aliases that allow feature specs to
>   read more as customer tests and acceptance tests.

You can simply replace `describe` (or `context`) with `feature` when writing feature specs. The `feature` statement should work when nested, like `describe`.

Comment: I don't understand this explanation. If feature and scenario are as describe and it, it means that we can also add context into it right? I don't understand why you say replace describe (or context), when context is different than describe.

Comment: `context` is also an alias for `describe`; they are interchangeable.

Comment: Oush. So I could place a before(:each) right after a 'general' feature, and then inside I can also put more (particular) features nested... Right?

Comment: Yes, describe blocks can be nested. You can also add `before` sections within nested blocks.