# how can I use feature and scenario in RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec

according to this post, `feature` and `describe` are interchangeable:

[How to add context in a feature rspec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23794609/how-to-add-context-in-a-feature-rspec)

However, when I use the following, it works, but when I substitute `describe` with `feature` it errors:

```
RSpec.describe "Billing UI Flows" do

    describe "User logs in and creates a new Billing Profile with PayPal" do

        context "User is new" do

        end
    end

    describe "User adds a site" do


    end


end
```

Answer (score 1):

> .. when I substitute `describe` with `feature` it errors

The `feature` method is provided by the `rspec-rails` gem. So, you probably just need to install `rspec-rails`.

> Feature specs are high-level tests .. [that] drive the application .. via its external interface ..
>   The feature and scenario DSL correspond to describe and it, respectively.
>   These methods are simply aliases that allow feature specs to read more as
>   customer and acceptance tests.
>   https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/feature-specs/feature-spec

Comment: Is there more to that.  I will try again.